# Output a DB2 SQL XML query to a unique XML file

Tags: xml, db2

Simplifying, I produce a set of XML elements with a SQL query such as:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "project", project) FROM project;
<project>project1</project>
<project>project2</project>
...
```

Now I need to wrap this sequence into a main "projects" element, and output this in a nice indented XML file.

I've tried as follows:

```
db2 -x "SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT XMLELEMENT(NAME "projects", XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME "project", project))) AS CLOB INCLUDING XMLDECLARATION) FROM project" >output.xml
```

And I get something like:

```
<projects><project>project1</project><project>project2</project>...</projects>
```

The XMLAGG works (it has wrapped everything into a main projects element). However, with 100k thousand projects, db2 complains with "SQL0433N  Value "... is too long. SQLSTATE=22001"

Also, output.xml is not indented (everything is in one line).

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Regards,
David

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a temporary table and put the opening and closing tag manually in there as well as the results from your query (be sure to add some spaces for the indention of your query results). If you have an ID column and put everything in the right order in the table, then you just need to query the table ( without id, but ordered by id) and save the results to a file.

Alternatively, you have a stored procedure go over the result of your query and output it in the formatted way. This might be slower than the first solution but needs probably less memory.

Last option you use your original query and post process your results, with an external tool.

Comment: thanks. yes, the option to write a simple external tool that takes a select query with only one xml column, and write this into a wrapped xml file seems a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You may not get the exact indentation you want, but you'll at least get one guaranteed line break per row if you don't XMLAGG the entire document into a single huge CLOB.

A common table expression is a convenient way of specifying a sorting column that does not have to appear in the final select statement.

```
WITH xmlheader( xmlrow, sort_seq ) AS ( VALUES ( 
' <?xml version="1.0" ?>'|| CHR( 10 ) || '<projects>', 1 ))
,
xmlbody( xmlrow, sort_seq ) AS ( VALUES( 
'<project>Replace this with your XMLSERIALIZE query, '
|| 'but only focus on generating XML for one project per row. '
|| 'This will enable you to specify a narrower data type, such AS VARCHAR(1000) '
|| 'for each row, and you will get each separate project '
|| 'followed by the normal newline at the end of each SQL row. '
|| 'No XMLAGG is necessary in this query.</project>', 2))
,
xmlfooter( xmlrow, sort_seq) AS ( VALUES( '</projects>', 3 ))

SELECT xmlrow FROM (
    SELECT xmlrow, sort_seq FROM xmlheader
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT xmlrow, sort_seq FROM xmlbody
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT xmlrow, sort_seq FROM xmlfooter
) AS fullxml 
ORDER BY sort_seq
```

Comment: thanks, it works! however it seems a bit of an artificial solution.
i would expect this task to be common enough to have an elegant simple  solution.

Comment: I agree it's a bit artificial and hackish, but it was done to avoid the CLOB data type, so it would work from anywhere, including shell scripts that use the DB2 CLP. No matter what, you should not need multiple statements or temp tables.

There are other options depending on what your constraints are. XMLAGG will neatly collapse all of the child elements down into one row, but you will have to serialize the document as a CLOB, which limits your options for handling it: 

1. EXPORT with LOB options,

or

2. Send the XMLAGG query from a program than can handle a LOB column in the result set.